# Unable to get renderStepIndicator working on react-native-step-indicator

Tags: react-native, jsx

I think I am not understanding the documentation correctly.

The documentation says: that is takes a Function that return a position: Number, or a stepStatus: which takes a String to render custom content inside step

My goal is to render a check mark instead of a number as it is by default.
I tried to return a string of 'test' and it does not work.

```
        <StepIndicator
            customStyles={customStyles}
            currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition}
            stepCount={this.state.stepCount}
            renderStepIndicator={() => {
            this.renderStepIndicator();
            }}
            labels={labels}
          />
```

and this is the function that return a string

```
     renderStepIndicator() {
         return 'test';
      }
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. also I want to return an icon of checkmark. I have seen people doin git but I am not sure how if this only takes a string or an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this function returns two parameters step position and step status. You can use this function like this,

```
<StepIndicator
    customStyles={customStyles}
    currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition}
    stepCount={this.state.stepCount}
    renderStepIndicator={(stepPosition,stepStatus) => {
       this.renderStepIndicator(stepPosition,stepStatus);
    }}
    labels={labels}
 />
```

And the render function is like,

```
renderStepIndicator(stepPosition, stepStatus) {
  return <Icon name={"check"} size={20} color={stepStatus === 'finished' ? "green" : "gray"} /> ;
}
```

This function render check icon. If you step was complete it show green check otherwise gray check.

For more details you can check this example,

https://github.com/24ark/react-native-step-indicator/blob/master/example/src/HorizontalStepIndicator.tsx

Comment: somehow it did not work. it does not render the image it just show a solid colored step instead

Comment: For image you can replace icon with image like, <Image source={imageNameOrImageURL} resizemode={"contain"} style={{height:ImageHeight, width:ImageWidth}} />

Comment: For some reason nothing get rendered, regardless if it is an image, Icon or text. the default numbers disappear and nothing get rendered inside the progress dots.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does not work for me so tried some changes and after some time I got this working solution if some are still facing this issue try using this code.

**1. Put this code in your StepIndicator props**

```
renderStepIndicator={({ position, stepStatus }) =>
          renderStepIndicatorRender(position, stepStatus)
        }
```

**2. Create a function to render the icon**

```
const renderStepIndicatorRender = (stepPosition, stepStatus) => {
return stepStatus === "finished" ? (
  <Icon name="check" size={12} color="#fff" />
) : (
  <Text>{stepPosition}</Text>
);
```